# how to get string content at each line in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string which contains a small code which is run dynamically.
But i want to store each line of string in separate datastructure and also count the lines.

```
string CodeStr = @"using System";

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

For counting lines :

```
        int count = 0;
        int position = 0;
        while ((position = CodeStr.IndexOf('\n', position)) != -1)
        {
            count++;
            position++;       
        }
```

but i dont know how to get content at each line like

line 1 : using System;

line 2 : namespace ConsoleApplication2

line 3 : { and so on for the complete string.

Comment: @MatthewWatson there is no file

Comment: Bit confused as what you are actually trying here?

Comment: `String.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Comment: what about splitting string with '\n' character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply split the string using [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) if the `string` is in code:

```
string[] lines = CodeStr.Split( new string[] { Environment.NewLine }
                              , StringSplitOptions.None
                              );
```

Or, if the file is read from disk, use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(yourFilePath);
```